# parsing error when sending double from android to php with hessian

Tags: java, php, hessian

I want to send a double value from my android client to the PHP server using hessian but either the writeDouble function on the client or the parseDouble function on the server has an error. (We transmit many different data types correctly, only the double give us trouble :))

The double values are longitude and latitude for example:

sent from android client: 14,30485725402832

received at server: 1.0474191691834E-321

android encoding:

```
public void writeDouble(double value) throws IOException
{
   long bits = Double.doubleToLongBits(value);

   os.write('D');
   os.write((byte) (bits >> 56));
   os.write((byte) (bits >> 48));
   os.write((byte) (bits >> 40));
   os.write((byte) (bits >> 32));
   os.write((byte) (bits >> 24));
   os.write((byte) (bits >> 16));
   os.write((byte) (bits >> 8));
   os.write((byte) (bits));
}
```

php decoding:

```
function parseDouble($code, $num){
            $bytes = $this->read(8);
            if(HessianUtils::$littleEndian)
                    $bytes = strrev($bytes);
            $double = unpack("dflt", $bytes);
    return $double['flt'];
    }
```

btw: we also have an iPhone client send the double - works fine ...

iphone encoding:

```
(void)encodeDouble:(double)realv forKey:(NSString*)key;
{
   if (key) [self writeTypedObject:key];
   [self writeChar:'D'];
   [self writeInt64:(int64_t)(*((double*)(&realv)))];
}
```

Comment: Can you give an example of a value you sent and what it was received as?

Comment: Also, what does the correctly working iPhone code look like? I assume it is in C and thus not an exact duplicate of the Java...

Comment: i added the iphone code and an example of the sent/received double values to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that iOS is little-endian, I think you want to encode your `double` in the opposite order in the Java code.

Comment: you were somehow right :) it is a little/big-endian problem. In detail,  the problem is that the php hessian library has an error -> the $littleEndian variable is never set... that's why it parses wrong

Comment: as for the solution, just use `Long.reverseBytes(bits);`